# Concatenation of detail values in PowerBI

Tags: powerbi

I am designing a PowerBI report using DirectQuery on a database.
In the database I have tables for persons, languages, and a link table telling which language a person speaks.
Example:

```
Persons
-------
Anna
Jane
John
Luis

Languages
---------
English
French
Spanish

Persons_Languages
-----------------
Anna   English
Anna   French
Jane   English
Jane   French
Luis   English
Luis   French
Luis   Spanish
```

I would like a report in PowerBI of the most common languages combinations. For example, in this case both Anna and Jane speak English+French, while Luis speaks English+French+Spanish. The desired report would show:

```
English+French          2
English+French+Spanish  1
```

Since I am trying to learn PowerBI, I need to exclude any solution at the database level.

Comment: Using [DirectQuery limits your ability](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/desktop-use-directquery#limitations-of-directquery) to create things like calculated tables. I'm not sure if this is possible with this kind of connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Alexis Olson is right, working with direct link, can't allow you to build measures/calcolated tables on data.

You have here 2 choices:
1- change from direct link to import and then build your ad hoc measure/table
2- directly build your measure on the source database, and then access the table from PBI

Good luck ;)